# WordPress login/register custom CSS not working?

Tags: css

A small but annoying problem is that in my WordPress (Elementor) login/register form `wp-login.php?action=register` the "Registration confirmation will be emailed to you" text is grey on black.

I used right click and Inspect and it's called `reg_passmail` (I think). It changes successfully if you change it in Styles pane but adding this custom CSS isn't working... any ideas why?!?

[image]

```
/* This isn't working for some reason */
#reg_passmail {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the custom CSS?

Comment: In WordPress Menu ---> Appearance ---> Customise ---> Additional CSS

Comment: The code in `Additional CSS` is not working for the admin pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [register_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_form/) hook. Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
<?php
add_action( 'register_form', 'custom_css_register_form' );
function custom_css_register_form() {
    ?>
        <style>
            #reg_passmail {
                color: white !important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: If it works, you can mark this as [accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), so it can be useful for someone else reading this question in the future.

Comment: OK thanks will do